# I cannot just seem to reference the child under User ID from firebase database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have tried all the ways to reference the child (username) under, UID generated for displaying a string value in text view from Firebase database, but it won't just show up

Database:

[image]

```
DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child("uid").child("username");
    mDatabaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                String username = Objects.requireNonNull(dataSnapshot.getValue()).toString();
                mName.setText(("username" + username ));
            } else {
                mName.setText(null);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

TextView:

[image]

it always goes to the else part, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The child that you are referencing in your code does not exist in the database, that is why it always goes to the else part.

```
DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child("uid").child("username");
```

In your database, you don't have a child called `uid`, under the node `Users` you have different user ids, therefore you need to do the following:

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
String userId     = user.getUid();
DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(userId).child("username");
```

This will retrieve the id of the current login user and you will be able to retrieve the `Username`.