# Find firebase user by a part of the email address?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a set of users with email addresses like the following (along with other users):

- userA@example.com
- userB@example.com
- userC@example.com

Is there a way to find all users with an email address ending on `@example.com` or starting with `user`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no api in firebase authentication, that will enable you to do that. If you want to find the user per ending of email address `@example.com`, then you have to connect the firebase authentication to firebase database. Then when you query the data, you can `split` the `string` retrieved.

Comment: Do you have a link on how to "connect the firebase authentication to firebase database"?

Comment: @BrunoLM What I meant is that you need to use the authentication uid in your database and under that node, you can then add the email. For example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55209464/i-cannot-just-seem-to-reference-the-child-under-user-id-from-firebase-database.. this will get all the emails